# How to include / exclude directories in duplicity

Tags: duplicity

I'm using duplicity to backup some of my files. The man page is kind of confusing, regarding the include/exclude Patterns. I'd like to backup the following things:

```
/storage/include
/otherthings
```

but NOT

```
/storage/include/exclude
```

The Include-File currently looks:

```
+ /storage/include
- /storage/include/exclude
+ /otherthings
- **
```

Duplicity is called as followed:

```
/usr/bin/duplicity --include-globbing-filelist /Path/to/file/above / target
```

It simply doesn't work. Every time it backups, it also includes the files in /storage/include/exclude.

Comment: How do you know that is the syntax of the include-file? Also, maybe this would work: `duplicity --exclude-filelist "/Path/to/filelist/without-or+/to-exclude" / target`. (note: I don't use `duplicity`, just a suggestion based on the manual page I found)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [file selection section](https://web.archive.org/web/20140313212914/https://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect10) of the `duplicity` man page states:

> Each file selection condition either matches or doesn’t match a given file. A given file is excluded by the file selection system exactly when the first matching file selection condition specifies that the file be excluded; otherwise the file is included.

This relates to the --include / --exclude command line options priority, but the manual page later you find the relevant info for the `--include-globbing-filelist` option you use:

```
The --include-globbing-filelist and --exclude-globbing-filelist options also 
specify filelists, but each line in the filelist will be interpreted as a
globbing pattern the way --include and --exclude options are interpreted
(although "+ " and "- " prefixing is still allowed). For instance, if the
file "globbing-list.txt" contains the lines:

    dir/foo
    + dir/bar
    - ** 

Then --include-globbing-filelist globbing-list.txt would be exactly the same
as specifying --include dir/foo --include dir/bar --exclude ** on the command
line.
```

What happens is that `/storage/include/exclude` matches the first line, it therefore it is included. You should in general use more specific statements before less specific ones. The following should work for you:

```
- /storage/include/exclude
+ /storage/include
+ /otherthings
- **
```

Comment: Nice. It works. One more question: If i only want to exclude, say "txt"-Files in the exclude-Directory. How do i do this? - /storage/include/exclude/*.txt didn't work

Comment: @int2000 That should IMHO work, but such patterns are not explicitly [tested](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/duplicity/0.6-releases/view/head:/testing/tests/selectiontest.py#L319). So there might be an issue. Could you use `/storage/include/exclude/**.txt`, or at least try if that works. If not you might have found a bug in the matching code in selection.py

Comment: How does this relate to the source parameter of the duplicity command? Would the dir/foo in your first example be /source/path/dir/foo ?