# Duplicity include/exclude directories & symlinks

Tags: backup, symlink, duplicity

I'm trying to configure Duplicity to perform a system-wide settings backup. Among other things, I'd like to backup settings in `/etc/portage/`, the file `/usr/src/linux/.config` and the KDE autostart scripts located in `/home/myuser/.kde4/Autostart/`. This is what my current `backup-include-list.txt` looks like:

```
/etc/timezone

/usr/src/linux/.config

- /etc/portage/bin/
- /etc/portage/make.conf.catalyst
- /etc/portage/make.profile
- /etc/portage/postsync.d/
- /etc/portage/repo.postsync.d/
/etc/portage

/home/myuser/.bashrc
/home/myuser/.kde4/Autostart/
```

The command I use to run Duplicity:

```
duplicity -v8 --asynchronous-upload --full-if-older-than 30D --include-filelist backup-include-list.txt --exclude '**' / $REMOTE_URL
```

`/etc/timezone` and `.bashrc` are backed up successfully. However, nothing in either of `/etc/portage/` or `/home/myuser/.kde4/Autostart/` is copied. Furthermore, Duplicity doesn't handle the symlink `/usr/src/linux/` and after restoring I end up with

```
$ ls -l testrestore/usr/src
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20  4 June  16:20 linux -> linux-3.18.12-gentoo
```

My version is `duplicity 0.6.25`.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117761/howto-include-exclude-diretories-in-duplicity) is of no help, since I have pretty much the same situation and the proposed solution doesn't work for me. How do I fix the included/excluded directories and the symlink problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use --include-globbing-filelist instead. before 0.7.03 ordinary file list parameters were globbing agnostic.

wrt. the symlink issue. this might be a corner case as the symlink resolves to a destination in an excluded folder. try including

```
 + /usr/src/linux*/.config
```

generally use either globbing syntax or not, as outlined in the answer you linked above.

good luck ..ede/duply.net

Comment: Thank you, it did work! With one minor drawback: the symlink is not preserved, and I end up with all `.config` files from all `linux-3.xx.xx-gentoo` folders. But that's not a major problem.